# Policy rate and the mean of the stochastic discount factor: what is exogenous?

Tags: monetary-policy, asset-pricing

Let us fix the length of one period to be the tenor of the risk-free rate targeted by the central bank, e.g. 1 day. There exists a stochastic discount factor (SDF, a.k.a. pricing kernel).

I am confronted with what to me seems like the chicken-and-egg problem. The SDF is by definition determined by investors' preferences (utility function), but its mean, which is by definition directly related to the risk-free rate, is set exogenously by the central bank. Would someone know of a unified framework to resolve my concern? Is it a concern at all?